# Writing a long (primitive type) to a file in Java

Tags: java, file, long-integer

Hi all,

I have an array of long that I would like to write into a .txt file that I can later open in gedit (one number per line). I get those values by using a subtraction of two instances of System.currentTimeMillis().

I use the following code:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("latency.txt"));
for (int i = 0; i < USER_LIMIT; ++i) {
    out.write(latency[i] + "\n");
}
out.close();
```

When looking at the file, I do see:

```
0
1
1
0
```

I believe the string concatenation converted the long into an integer. If I use the DataOutputStream, then I cannot read it back with gedit or any notepad/text editor, it just looks like garbage (I believe it's writing bytes).

Would anyone please let me know how I can fix my problem please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are the values of `latency[i]`?

Comment: Can you tell us what the first few numbers in the array are supposed to be?

Comment: String concatenation did not convert the `long` into an `int`.

Comment: I actually did not check the value of latency[i], and I should have (my bad). I will look at it right now. I assumed because the system returns milliseconds that 1 was way to small. Let me double check the values.

Comment: @Jary: Really, that should have been the *first* thing you checked!

Comment: My bad, the values actually ARE that small. I guess my question was just stupid. I apologize to have made you guys lose your time!

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: You are right and I really apologize. I was really convinced for some reason that something was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. What you think is in `latency` ... isn't.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    long[] latency = { 123456789000L, 234567890000L, 345678901000L };

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("latency.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        out.write(latency[i] + "\n");
    }
    out.close();
}
```

produces:

```
$ more latency.txt 
123456789000
234567890000
345678901000
```

When you're having a problem with code like this, it's often beneficial to write a small test case to narrow down the problem.

Comment: No worries. We've all seen the bottom of at least a couple rabbit holes :)

Answer (score 0):

Cast to a Long and use toString:

```
out.write(((Long)latency[i]).toString() + "\n");
```

Or just use the static toString:

```
out.write(Long.toString(latency[i]) + "\n");
```

Comment: If `latency[i]` is already a `long`, this should make zero difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you use DataOutputStream to write a long it is using a different encoding of your data than gedit understands.

One of the most common encodings used for text files is ASCII. With this each byte represents a character in a table. This table has 128 characters. When you write a string to a file using Java the way you're doing it this is what is happening and gedit understands that encoding. If you convert a long to a string the maximum size a long can be would look like: 9223372036854775807. That would take up 19 bytes.

A long in Java is 64 bits or 8 bytes. When you use DataOutputStream a long gets written to the file as 8 bytes. A text editor like gedit does not understand this encoding.

What further complicates things is encodings such as UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to append the newline to the number, so you can break them apart and avoid this problem. Try this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < USER_LIMIT; ++i ) {
    out.write( String.valueOf(latency[i]) ); // Or Long.toString(long)
    out.write( '\n' ); // Or simply out.newLine() 
}
```

Comment: Except that it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I get the following error in that case: The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (long) (Eclipse)

Comment: @Jary: Oh, well then you'll have to cast the long to an `int` or use a different method of printing. My real point was that you don't need to append the newline to the number before you print it.

Comment: @Shakedown: There should be no problem with the string concatenation operation.  What is more, your code above won't compile (as the OP has just found).

Comment: For out.write( latency[i] ); latency[i] is of type "long" and the BufferedWrite that I use cannot write "long" directly.

Comment: @Jary: I see, you're trying to use the `write(String)` method - I've updated my answer to show how.

Comment: @Brian Roach: True. Well...nothing functionally wrong, but had he written it differently he probably would've been able to figure it out  quicker.